# Access Denied Domain Users Ubuntu 14.04 using Powerbroker

Tags: active-directory

I am binding computers running Ubuntu 14.04 to our AD environment.  I followed all the sets to configure the system and I am able to login with a domain account.  However, when I restart the computer and try to login with the same domain account I get an "Access Denied" error.  Has anyone had a similar issue to this?